# Duplicate camera stream

Tags: c#, .net, c++, camera

I need to make a program that would allow me to capture camera stream with my 2 other programs simultaneously. Basically I need the functionality that ManyCams (http://www.manycam.com/) offers.

How can I do this? I'm interested in a free c++ library, or some C#/C++ .net solution.

Comment: I don't quite understand why somebody downrated my question. Maybe it sounds like I want somebody to do the whole job for me. Well, I don't, I'm just looking for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, one easy step will be "share" rather than "duplicate" camera streams, your application can capture camera streams then provide api to share it between multiple applications. [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you probably need to have good understanding of how hardware work and know how to develop a driver for it. What you should do is to get the graphic from usb device's driver and use what you get from your camera as input source for your own virtual camera drivers.